# Multiple jQuery instances with vars, events, and DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, global-variables, instance-variables

I am working on a project that started out as simply building a function that takes an argument (XML file) and converts it into a HTML/CSS structure (earlier version to be found [here](http://bramvanroy.be/projects/html-trees/)). This worked great. However, I'd like to implement more options and more flexibility. I've read on the topic (e.g. [1](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/), [2](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/multiple-instances-of-jquery-plugin-on-one-page/), [3](http://pioul.fr/architecture-of-a-multi-instantiable-jquery-plugin)) but I can't wrap my head around it.

My plugin has a lot instance-specific needs:

- variables
- options
- event handlers

and there are some important options:

- display a fullscreen version
- display a normal version (comes with a "open fs version" button)
- specify a container for the normal version
- set fontsize of normal version
- set possible fontsizes for fs version (for zooming in and out the tree)
- set a class that, when a user clicks on an element with that class, opens the fs version

I'll sketch the base structure of the current state of the plugin.

The two first options are the most important ones. But default to `true`, and if a user has both of them on `false`, the plugin won't execute.

The plugin then assigns global variables and creates new DOM elements based on this information. In practice it looks something like this (note that the global variables are declared at the top of my script).

```
function initVars(args) {
    fontsizes = fsFontSizes;
    errorContainer = $(".tv-error");
    var trees = [],
        tooltips = [];

    if (args.normalView) {
        normalView = true;
        $(args.container).append('<div id="tree-visualizer" style="display: none"></div>');
        SS = $("#tree-visualizer");
        var SSHTML = '<div class="tv-error" style="display: none"><p></p></div>' +
            '<div class="tree" style="font-size: ' + args.fontSize + 'px;"></div>' +
            '<aside class="tooltip" style="display: none"><ul></ul>' +
            '<button>&#10005;</button></aside>';
        if (args.fsView) {
            SSHTML += '<button class="tv-show-fs">Fullscreen</button>';
        }
        SS.append(SSHTML);

        treeSS = SS.find(".tree");
        tooltipSS = SS.find(".tooltip");

        trees.push("#tree-visualizer .tree");
        tooltips.push("#tree-visualizer .tooltip");
    }
    if (args.fsView) {
        fsView = true;
        $("body").append('<div id="fs-tree-visualizer-" class=""fs-tree-visualizer" style="display: none"></div>');
        FS = $("#fs-tree-visualizer");
        var FSHTML = '<div class="tv-error" style="display: none"><p></p></div>' +
            '<div class="tree"></div><aside class="tooltip" style="display: none"><ul></ul>' +
            '<button>&#10005;</button></aside><div class="zoom-opts"><button class="zoom-out">-</button>' +
            '<button class="zoom-default">Default</button><button class="zoom-in">+</button>' +
            '<button class="close">&#10005;</button></div>';
        FS.hide().append(FSHTML);
        treeFS = FS.find(".tree");
        tooltipFS = FS.find(".tooltip");
        zoomOpts = FS.find(".zoom-opts");
        zoomCounter = Math.round(fontSizes.length / 2);

        trees.push("#fs-tree-visualizer .tree");
        tooltips.push("#fs-tree-visualizer .tooltip");
    }

    if (args.fsBtn != "") {
        $(args.fsBtn).addClass("tv-show-fs");
    }

    anyTree = $(trees.join());
    anyTooltip = $(tooltips.join());
}
```

You'll see that I am working with IDs which makes it hard to work with multiple instances. One way to solve this, I thought, would be to add a class for styling, and add an ID to each instance by using a global counter that keeps track of the instantiations (`counter++` on each instance). Note that `anyTree` is used when I wish to target FS tree as well as the normal views tree. This does NOT mean that I want to target all trees of all instances! This has to be restricted per instance as well.

So my question is, how do I allow for multiple instances and especially: how can I move from global variables to local variables without losing the power that I have now? At this moment I can work with global variables and access each variable wherever I want. But how can I restrict the global variable per instance? Work with that counter as I proposed?

Also, where do I assign events? Currently this is how my plugin initializes (I left out global variables and functions):

```
$.treeVisualizer = function(xml, options) {
        var args = $.extend({}, $.treeVisualizer.defaults, options);

        /* At least one of the arguments (default true) have to be true */
        if (args.normalView || args.fsView) {
            initVars(args);
            loadXML(xml);

        } else {
            console.error("Cannot initialize Tree Visualizer: either the container " +
                "does not exist, or you have set both normal and fullscreen view to " +
                "false, which does not make sense.");
        }

        /* Event handlers -- only after we've initiated the variables to globals */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Show fs-tree-visualizer tree
            $(".tv-show-fs").click(function(e) {
                // Show corresponding fullscreen version
                FS.show();
                // Execute some functions
                sizeTreeFS();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Zooming
            zoomOpts.find("button").click(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                // Do something
            });

            anyTree.on("click", "a", function(e) {
                // Do something, and execute function: has to 
                // target the right tooltip
                tooltipPosition();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
```

Is this the right place to put event handlers?

Comment: Adding a working jsfiddle to your question would get better answers. Having an almost-working jsfiddle is good, too :)

Comment: @o.v. Will this do? https://github.com/BramVanroy/tree-visualizer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That XML visualizer looks nice.
I have a couple of pointers for you.

First off, you create a jquery-component/widget/plugin by using $.fn.componentName instead of $.componentName.

```
$.fn.treeVisualizer
```

Second, I would recommend to move all the global values into options, or local variables into your component. The code snippet you provided should work. Every global value that could be different for every instance has to be an option.

```
$.fn.myComponent(options){
  var defaults = {
     option1: true,
     option2: 5
  };
  options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);//defaults and options are being merged into {}
  var constantValue = 15; //values that won't change, you can just move locally from global
}
```

Third, for your global functions, I would suggest putting them in a self-invoking function together with the component, so that the component can access the function and they are not unnecesarely global.

```
(function initComponent(){
  $.fn.myComponent(){
    someFunction();
  }
  function someFunction(){
    //do something
  }
})();
//immediately invoke function/ self-invoking function
```

Or you can put the functions inside the component scope.

```
$.fn.myComponent = function(){
  someFunction();
  function someFunction(){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Fourth, I would recommend using classes instead of id's. You could indeed solve this by making sure the id is unique by keeping track of the amount of instances there are, but simply use classes (fe, xml-id-1). Or you could also use a data-id/data-xml-id attribute. Don't worry about querying elements with the same class in different components, I'll get to that in the next pointer.

```
$jqueryElement.addClass('xml-id-'+id);
$('.xml-id-'+id);//you can query it by class-name like this
```

Or if you want to take advantage of data-attributes (which I recommend over classes because the html is easier to read and has more meaning imo)

```
$jqueryElement.attr('data-xml-id', id); //fe <div data-xml-id="1"></div>
$('[data-xml-id="'+id+'"]'); //you can query it like this
```

Lastly, every query and event needs to be relative to your component, so that you only search for elements and add event within the instance of your component. This makes sure that you don't accidently perform actions on another instance of your component.

```
$.fn.myComponent=function(){
  $('[data-xml-id="1"]'); //this queries the whole DOM, don't do this!
  var $el = this.find('[data-xml-id="1"]'); //this only looks for matching elements within the current instance of the component
  $el.click(function(){// also add events to elements you searched within your components
    //do something
  );
}
```

Then finally initialize your component like so.

```
$('#tree1').treeVisualizer(xml,
  {
    fullscreen: true
  }
);
$('#tree2').treeVisualizer(xml);
```

---

Extra question from comments:

### Find method

The find method acts just the same as the global query method, with the difference that it only searches within the DOM of the jQueryObject.

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.
>   Source: [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Example:

```
var footer = $('footer');
footer.find('div');// searches for div's inside the footer
```

### this usage

Inside a plugin `this` refers to the jQueryObject you initialized the plugin on.

```
$.fn.myComponent = function(){
  console.log(this);// refers to $el
}

var $el = $('#id');
$el.myComponent();
```

Inside an event callback, this refers to the native element where you attached the event handler too. You have to wrap it in a jQuery object to perform jQuery action upon it.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  console.log(this); //prints out the button that was clicked
  $(this).css('background','#000'); //wrap native button element in jQuery object and perform jQuery methods on it
});
```

Whenever you are unsure where `this` refers too, simply log it to the console.
With this info, you can see that when you use `this.find('.tree-structure')` inside your component, you will indeed only search for elements with the 'tree-structure'-class inside the jQuery-object you initialized the component with.

Comment: You can also put constant values in the self-invoking function instead of locally in your component.

Comment: Let me know if I forgot to address any of your questions. If you put your project on github, I'd be happy to help out on any issues you have.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look and try some stuff out the following days. I'm still a bit confused as to how `this.find('.an-element')` works. Could you given an example? Let's say you have two instances, and the plugin creates new elements in HTML in the target div with a class `.tree-structure`. How would you then select `.tree-structure` for a single instance? Simply `this.find('.tree-structure')`?  Finally, is it recommended to put all functions into the plugin declaration? Thanks for the help so far (+1)!

Comment: @BramVanroy I provided extra info regarding the usage of `.find` and `this'

Comment: @BramVanroy Here's a [free jQuery](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery) course that helped me when I was learning about jQuery from codeschool

Comment: Thanks a lot so far! I haven't had any time to look at this yet, but I put the project on GitHub. Feel free to take a look! https://github.com/BramVanroy/tree-visualizer

Comment: Hi there! I'm working on it at the moment and I still got some questions. Can you help me out? If you fork the project [here](https://github.com/BramVanroy/tree-visualizer) you'll see that it doesn't work. Currently I am getting an error when I try to join an array of two variables. Probably because I defined those variables as `this.find(".some-class")`. Can you lend a hand?

Comment: I am starting to better understand what's going on - that's nice. One thing I can't wrap my head around, though, is how you can call different instances on the same element. Is that even possible? When I try `$(body).treeVisualizer(...)` two times with different XML, things go haywire - which I assume is to be expected if `$(body) == this`. But isn't there a way around this? I guess working with unique data-attributes as you suggested, but how would I then only target the items that I want? Any thoughts?

Comment: @BramVanroy I simply suggest not doing that, or emptying/destroying before reinitializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Code below is a basic format I use when I make a plugin. I hope this help you find solutions to some of your concerns.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.FUNCTIONNAME = function(options) {
        var obj = $(this);
        var opts = $.extend({
            OPTION1 : 'OPTION1 VALUE',
            OPTION2 : 'OPTION2 VALUE',
        }, options);
    }

    function FUNCTIONNAME(PARAMETER) {
        FUNCTION CONTENT
        IF YOU WANT TO USE OPTION VALUE,
        YOU CAN CALL IT BY A FORM AS opts.OPTION1
    }        

    obj.find($('ID OR CLASS DOESNT MATTER')).FUNCTIONNAME(PARAMETER);
    // this will make the plugin only work for this element

    return this; // or you can each() over every functions and return it
})(jQuery);
```

+And I recommend you not to use document.ready inside the plugin. Event handlers can be put anywhere.

EDIT: this -> obj

Comment: You can just use `this.find('ID OR CLASS DOESNT MATTER')` instead of `this.find($('ID OR CLASS DOESNT MATTER'))`.

Comment: And overriding the this keyword is not possible I believe. Either way, this is already a jQuery object so what you're trying to do there is redundant.

Comment: @sniels I didn't know that. Redundant was my mistake while writing the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the DOM element you're inserting without re-querying  with [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) returning a reference to the inserted elements

```
//before:
$(args.container).append('<div id="tree-visualizer" style="display: none"></div>');
$SS = $("#tree-visualizer"); //prefixing variables with $ when referencing jquery objects

//after:
$SS = $('<div style="display: none"></div>').appendTo( $(args.container) );
```

If you apply click bindings as part of init code

```
$SS.append(SSHTML).on('click', '.tv-show-fs', function() {
    $FS.show();
});
```

you'll notice `SS` and `FS` can now be both locally scoped.

Alternatively you can de-couple your "show in full screen" functionality from the core plugin and avoid duplicating functionality. A naive approach could be to toggle some styling, but even if you want to manipulate DOM you get the idea. It's not like you can have more than one meaningful fullscreen instance at the same time.

```
$SS.append(SSHTML).on('click', '.tv-show-fs', function() {
    $SS.toggleClass('tree-visualiser__fullscreen');
});
```